# Trying to combine two byte arrays of image data into one bitmap for WPF button

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, processing

First off, I'd like to state that I know very little about the imaging namepspaces in .Net.

I have two byte arrays of image data that I would like to merge into a bitmap for a WPF button.  I would like to do all of this in the C# code is possible.  The background image is either a jpeg or png, and the overlay image is definitely a png with transparent areas.  The overlay image is one of a "Sold Out" banner that I would like to add to the original image.  I have a function that will convert either image to something the button.background will handle.

I have tried this for both images and it works just fine. The next part is the part due to my lack of familiarity of the image processing in .Net that has me stumped.  I've seen something about a RenderTargetBitmap, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the base/background bitmap into it to render the second one on top, maybe there's another way of doing this.  Here's a copy of the function that I have inherited from a previous coder/project.

I have to take the byte array and convert it over to something I can assign directly to the button.background :

```
public static BitmapImage ByteArrayToImageBrush(this byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

I have defined a new class that inherits from button call CategoryButton, that has some other misc. properties.  I can successfully place either image as the background for the button when I create the buttons in code with the following:

```
CategoryButton catbtn = new CategoryButton();
catbtn.Background = new ImageBrush(ByteArrayToImageBrush(bgImageByteArray);
// * or *
catbtn.Background = new ImageBrush(ByteArrayToImageBrush(overlayImageByteArray);
```

So I know that function works well enough. But how does one get either the byte array or resultant ImageBrush into something that I can "add"/merge the second overlay image onto and then get that into a format that can be used for the button background? I know that this is a lot of question, but I'm stumped and I and getting frustrated in trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to put two stacked `Image` controls like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="image" Stretch="None" />
    <Image Name="overlay" Stretch="None" />
</Grid>
```

And just assign the appropriate `ImageSource` to the `Source` of each control.

If you really need to combine the two images into one, you can do something like that:

```
private static ImageSource CombineImageWithOverlay(byte[] imageBytes, byte[] overlayBytes)
{
    var image = GetImageFromBytes(imageBytes);
    var overlay = GetImageFromBytes(overlayBytes);
    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var context = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawImage(image, new Rect(0, 0, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight));
        context.DrawImage(overlay, new Rect(0, 0, overlay.PixelWidth, overlay.PixelHeight));
    }
    var result = new RenderTargetBitmap(image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, image.DpiX, image.DpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    result.Render(visual);
    return result;
}

private static BitmapImage GetImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.StreamSource = stream;
        img.EndInit();
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay... but with what you gave me I was about to figure something out...  It works the way I need ot so Thanks...